# Did Hitler design the VW Beetle?

Tags: history, adolf-hitler

It if often cited that [Adolf Hitler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolf_Hitler) designed the **VW Beetle**. Is there any truth to this myth, did he perhaps commission it?

It seems strange that a car supposedly designed in the 30s could have been in production for so long.

Comment: There is a joke that the soviet era muskovitch car has four doors because when it was the (two-door) prototype was presented to Stalin, the dictator sat in the front passenger seat and told the car designer to get in... Point being that while the Hitler most likely didn't play an active role in the development, I'm certain that his approval was sought throughout the design process.

Comment: It may seem strange that a car model was produced for 65 years, but it was gradually updated. A 1949 interior http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:1949_VW_dash_.jpg and a 1990 interior http://www.flickr.com/photos/benteen/2935960023/in/photostream/ helps visualize that. But the car never got a big redesign, it was just gradually improved, which is testament to the genius of the design. And you know, it still looks kinda cool and cute.

Comment: @crasic - Nitpick. The proper car name is "Moskvitch" as opposed to "muskovitch".

Comment: Where is this often cited? I never heard it. Hitler wasn't a designer, and did not work in the automobile industry.

Comment: I'm commenting the above answers. I'm not providing new sources. You can also check the Steyer 50, an Austrian Bettle lookalike made in the same era. Hitler was Austrian.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**No, he did not design it**. It was designed by Ferdinand Porsche.

It was however commissioned by Hitler. Hitler met with Porsche in 1933 and asked him to develop a cheap good car affordable for everybody, a "Peoples Car". Porsche was a natural choice for this, because he in fact already had developed such a car, the Porsche Type 12, produced by Zündapp from 1931.

[image: Porsche Type 12]

In 1932 he produced the Porsche Type 32, a car quite strikingly similar to the Volkswagen, including having a 4-cylinder air cooled engine.

[image: Porsche Type 32]

Claiming that Hitler designed the Beetle is hence nonsense, as Porsche's Type 32 has most of the striking design and many of the Beetle's technical elements in place, well before Hitler and Porsche ever met, and **looks more like a Beetle than the alleged sketches by Hitler**.

Further reading, and sources:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volkswagen_Beetle
- http://newbeetle.org/forums/rumors-insights/31170-porsche-type-12-a.html

Comment: It should also be noted that the VW Beetle also copies much from the Tatra V570. There is some evidence it was Hitler's intention.[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Ledwinka#Volkswagen_controversy] In 1961 Volkswagen paid Ringhoffer-Tatra 3,000,000 Deutsche Marks in an out of court settlement.

Answer (score 14):

**There is no reliable evidence that this is the case**

### What information is available?

According to the [Hitler Historical Museum](http://www.hitler.org/), possibly biased, Hitler did design it on a piece of paper or a napkin.

> Sitting at a restaurant table in Munich in the summer of 1932, Hitler designed the prototype for what would become the immensely successful Beetle design for Volkswagen
> —[source](http://www.hitler.org/artifacts/volkswagen/)

However — according to practically any other source I could find — Hitler commissioned the Beetle to [Ferdinand Porsche](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferdinand_Porsche), and gave design specifications (speed, size, cost) - but the actual work was done by Porsche.

For example:

> Impressed by Porsche's design capabilities, Hitler delivered him the design brief of a car that could carry two adults and three children at a speed of 60mph with at least 33 mpg. The price was to be 1000 Reichmarks, not much more than a motorcycle at the time.
> —[source](http://www.volkswest.co.uk/beetle_history.html)

Given the possible bias of the museum, I am inclined to give more credence to the more common version: Hitler did indeed commission the Beetle, but did not do the actual design of it.

### What about the evidence?

There is clear evidence that Hitler commissioned the Beetle — see for example this picture of Hitler examining an early prototype at a Volkswagen factory with Porsche.

[image: Hitler and Porsche examine a Beetle]
<sub>(source: [hubimg.com](http://s2.hubimg.com/u/99721_f520.jpg))</sub>

Regarding the sketches — purportedly hand-drawn by the dictator himself — there are two versions circulating on the Internet and none of them seems to come from a reliable source.
Furthermore, they look very different — they can't possibly be both true.

All in all, I find this evidence unconvincing for the above reasons.

[image: sketch 1]

[image: sketch 2]
<sub>(source: [hitler.org](http://www.hitler.org/artifacts/volkswagen/volkswagen.jpg))</sub>

Comment: I think it's also worth noting this image of [Hitler examining a model VW](http://blog.sme.sk/blog/11207/194324/volkswagen-beetle-hitler-2.png). Mostly, I just find it bemusing, I don't think it really differentiates between the possibilities.